# Different css on posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, css-float, wordpress-theming

First I'm going to explain the problem. I have a wordpress website with a few pages. One of the pages is the page that shows the summary of all the articles.
This is all working fine. What I want to archieve is the following:

---

*Article 1 should be aligned to the left of the page, Article 2 should be aligned to the right and so on. (LEFT - RIGHT - LEFT - RIGHT - LEFT - ... )*

---

I have no idea how to start. I have done some research and maybe wp_count_posts() is going to help me but I can't fix it.

**Single.php** (template for 1 post)

```
get_header(); ?>

    <section class="news-area">
        <div class="wrapper" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php 
                $count = count_posts( $type, $perm );
                echo $count;
            ?> 
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>

            <?php group_joosen_post_nav(); ?>

            <?php
                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!--END wrapper-->
    </section>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**content.php** ("template" for all the posts)

```
<article class="teasers" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="datum">
                <div class="day">
                 <?php the_time('d') ?>
                 </div>
                 <div class="month">
                 /<?php the_time('m') ?>     
                 </div>
                 <div class="year">
                 <?php the_time('Y') ?>      
                 </div>
     </div>     
     <div class="teaserscontent">   
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'transport_joosen' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>


    <?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php the_content( __( 'Lees meer', 'transport_joosen' ) ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

Comment: Can you please post the code of the template from your page which is used to show the summary of all the articles?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this simply with CSS. Assuming the HTML has all `article` elements as siblings:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/53rh3/

```
article {
    width: 47%;
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 1%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```